# Generate DB usage in PHP Scripts

Tags: php, mysql, ide

This might seem to be a silly question but I was wondering if there any programs out there that would scan over a directory of PHP scripts and generate a report that states exactly what databases and tables are queried in each particular script?

Our database type is MySQL.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like [PHP Code Sniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer). It's a static analysis tool that can search through PHP code for certain rules. You may have to end up writing your own sniffing rules, but it might be somewhere you could start. I've used it to check PHP version updates and it's worked pretty well. Just search for 'php code sniffer custom standards' and you can find some useful stuff to help get started.